# Bot Framework v4 C# - Proactive messages

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, bots, botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm using Microsoft Graph in C# to interact with the Azure AD, now I need to build a teams bot that sends a welcome message to the user that was added to the directory, even if the user hasn't had a previous conversation with the bot. How can I implement that if the conversation reference is null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would require to install the bot app using Graph API and then get the conversation reference to send welcome message.

See following reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/proactive-bots-and-messages/graph-proactive-bots-and-messages?tabs=dotnet

Answer (score 0):

If the bot app is meant to be pre-installed for all users or a defined set of users in the organization, you can use Setup policies to install it - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-app-setup-policies . It will require the Teams administrator(s) in your organization to configure this.